# Как добавить анимацию на страницу?

Tags: javascript, leafletjs

Требуется по клику на контейнер показать на странице гиф анимацию, которая будет имитировать получение данных с сервера, т.е. появляется на пару секунд и после пропадает. Подскажите как решить данную проблему.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот пример кода. Думаю, что вставить гифку Вы сможете самостоятельно.

```js
var visible = false;
function onClick() {
    if (!visible) {
        visible = true;
        document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "block";
        setTimeout(function(){
            document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "none";
            visible = false;
        }, 2000);
    }
}
```

```css
#container {
    width: 10em;
    height: 5em;
    background-color: #dfd;
}
#loading {
    width: 8em;
    height: 3em;
    background-color: #aaf;
    border: 1px solid #00f;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="container" onclick="onClick()";>
    Click me!
    <div id="loading">Loading...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, дальше думаю как нибудь сам)